# Having problem with P410i smart array controller

Tags: raid

Please advice me how should i solve my RAID controller problem.

The problem is; The system doesn't detect RAID controller. I am using HP proliant DL360 G6 server with P410i smart array controller ( 0 cache memory ). In the Boot controller order, smart array controller haven't found.
In fact all the HDD attached with the system is not operational.

Comment: Have you tried moving the card temporarily to different slots? If it still doesn't work doing that I think you're going to have to call HP sorry, not sure if it's your controller or systemboard however.

Answer (score 0):

Physically checking your server's backplane to ensure nothing is simply loose should be the first order, if not already covered.

Comment: nothing is loose at the server's backplane.

Comment: Is this through physically reseating or a "spot" check?